# Pandas groupby, aggregate and filter strange behavior

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, split-apply-combine

I am trying to filter a dataset based on some aggregate measures: i need to find the `UserID`s that have performed between 5 and 15 transactions OR their average payment is between 0 and 1500.
This is my code:

```py
grouped_count = dataset.groupby('UserID').size()
user_count = grouped_count[(grouped_count >= 5) & (grouped_count <= 15)]
    
grouped_mean = dataset.groupby('UserID').mean()
user_mean = grouped_mean[(grouped_mean['Amount'] >= 0.0) & (grouped_mean['Amount'] <= 1500.0)]
```

The count part seems to be fine, but i have some concerns about the mean part: it seems the `groupby().mean()` runs correctly, but then the filtering part produces some rows showing a NaN value where they should be dropped instead.

```
> grouped_mean
            Amount      Authorized
UserID 
1        64.640000             1.0
2       750.000000             1.0
3       696.762857             1.0
4       424.666667             1.0
5       446.847500             1.0
...            ...             ...
58504   662.950000             1.0
58505  1578.008750             1.0
58506  2990.800848             1.0
58507    71.190000             1.0
58508    20.000000             1.0

[58508 rows x 2 columns]

> user_mean
           Amount      Authorized
UserID                                                      
1       64.640000             1.0
2      750.000000             1.0
3      696.762857             1.0
4      424.666667             1.0
5      446.847500             1.0
...           ...             ...
58504  662.950000             1.0
58505         NaN             1.0
58506         NaN             1.0
58507   71.190000             1.0
58508   20.000000             1.0

[58508 rows x 2 columns]
```

How can i get the result i need? Can i just add a `user_mean = user_mean.dropna(subset='Amount')` or is there a better way to do filtering after grouping and aggregating?

Comment: Try `grouped_mean = dataset.groupby('UserID')['Amount'].mean()` this should drop the NaN by default.  You're not taking the mean of Authorized also.  I think why you're getting those NaN is because the mean of Aurthorized is not NaN thus the records is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the solution by [Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6361531/scott-boston) in the comments solves the problem. The relevant columns must be selected before computing the mean.